# как снизить нагрузку при рисовании на Canvas wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

При рисовании на canvas'е загружает ЦП до 60%.

Нужно ли вместо этого юзать pathGeometry, возможно потом допилить функционал, минимально как в Paint'е?
Код:

```
private void MainCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mousePosition = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
        poly = new Polyline()
        {
            StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        };
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(poly);
    }

    private void MainCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        customCursor = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
        Canvas.SetTop(el, customCursor.Y - cursorRadius/2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(el, customCursor.X - cursorRadius/2);

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            poly.Points.Add(mousePosition);
            mousePosition = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
            poly.Points.Add(mousePosition);
        }
    }

    private void MainCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            polyUndoStack.Push(poly);
    }
```